# Redireccion de dominio a dominio por DNS

Tags: redirección, dominio

Como están?

Tengo 2 dominios, los cuales fueron comprados al mismo proveedor de dominios.

dominio.com está apuntado a hosting por registro A

dominio2.com no está apuntado a ningún hosting

la pregunta es: cómo hago para hacer que dominio2.com redireccione a dominio.com a través de DNS del dominio

yo no tengo acceso al hosting solo a los DNS de los dominios

desde ya muchas gracias!

saludos!!

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140310/discussion-on-question-by-gdougam-redireccion-de-dominio-a-dominio-por-dns).

Answer (score 0):

me refería al archivo de zona de dominio que tendría en los DNS-NAV (dns de navegación) algo parecido a eso

```
;zona dominio2.com generada automaticamente via provisioning
;hostmaster@isp-proveedor.   2001051100
;
@       IN      SOA     localhost       hostmaster.ISP.. (
;

    2006091100   ; Serial Number
        172800   ; Refresh  48 hours
          3600   ; Retry     1 hours
       1728000   ; Expire   20  days
        172800 ) ; Minimum  48 hours
                    IN              NS              dns1.isp-proveedor..
                    IN              NS              dns2.isp-proveedor..
                    IN              MX              10 relay.isp-proveedor..

;
localhost               IN              A               127.0.0.1
;

www                     IN              CNAME           dominio.com
ftp                     IN              CNAME           dominio.com
```

algo sí en tu archivo de zona de dominio

```
dominio2.com --> dominio.com
```

Comment: Eso no hace una redirección real, que es lo que pretende el OP. Eso sigue siendo el caso del `addon domain` que acabo de explicar en los comentarios, donde `dominio.com` alberga en su cuenta de hosting a `dominio2`, y luego, mediante diversos trucos o una redirección en ese hosting de dominio.com puede realizar la redirección con cabeceras HTTP 301 o 302.  (creo que ya lo sabes, pero por si acaso lo aclaro)